# Get(Serve) files from the blobstore in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

i worked on small project;the main functionalities of this project as follows:

1-Upload files from user's PC(using file upload in HTML(forms submission))

2-Compress these uploaded files into  single zip archive.

3-Store this Zip File in GAE BlobStore.

4-Get(Serve)this zip from the blobstore into the PC(download this zip to be available locally).

Step 1,2 and 3 were done correctly,but the problem in step 4;i can't download this Zip from the blobstore;
This is the code that i used:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from google.appengine.api import files
import cgi, cgitb ; cgitb.enable()
import StringIO
import zipfile
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
glob_blob_info="" 
class zip():
    def z(self):
        form = cgi.FieldStorage()
        zipstream=StringIO.StringIO()
        zfile = zipfile.ZipFile(file=zipstream,mode="w",compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
        file_upload = form['file[]']
        filename2 = file_upload.filename
        data=file_upload.file.read()
        zfile.writestr(filename2,data)
        zfile.close()
        zipstream.seek(0)
        zip_file = files.blobstore.create(mime_type='application/zip',_blobinfo_uploaded_filename='test.zip')
        with files.open(zip_file, 'a') as f:
            f.write(zipstream.getvalue())
        files.finalize(zip_file)
        blob_key = files.blobstore.get_blob_key(zip_file)
        print blob_key
        blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(blob_key)
        print blob_info
        global glob_blob_info
        glob_blob_info=blob_info
class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
  def get(self):
    print "doaa"
    global glob_blob_info 
    glob_blob_info = urllib.unquote(glob_blob_info)
    blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(glob_blob_info)
    self.send_blob(glob_blob_info,save_as=True)



def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication( [('/serve', ServeHandler),], debug=True)
    debug=True)
    c=zip()
    c.z()
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now `class zip()` is executed successfuly such that the zip archive containing the files that uploaded by the user was created successfuly in GAE Blobstore,but the problem exactly that the `class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):`didn't executed
when i ran this code i have this output:

```
Status: 404 Not Found 
Content-Type: text/html;
charset=utf-8 Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT 
Content-Length: 0
```

Have any ideas for this problem?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please stop posting nearly identical questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send_blob in GAE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880865/send-blob-in-gae)

Comment: @Nick Johnson:Sorry for that,but the problem still exist!!!

Comment: @Eng_Engineer: It's much better to edit your first question than to open a second question which is almost identical (even if the problem still exists).

Comment: @Stefan:Yes,that's correct,sorry for that,are you understand my question in this post??

Comment: @Eng_Engineer, no sorry, I don't have an answer.

Answer (score 1):

What part of serving a blob described [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html#Serving_a_Blob) is not working for you?

Comment: :This class not executed(class ServeHandler)and this is my problem??

Comment: :the application in main() itself doesn't execute.

Answer (score 1):

I know this maybe obvious but is your app.yaml set to handle that application path? That would give you a 404. Also why are you using a global here? I would avoid that. Pass it the URL safe blob key as part of the URL or on a URL param and get the blob info from that. If you use global with appengine you will have all sorts of potential issues.

I have used the blob store to do all sorts of file like things and never had an issue. Its most likely a problem with you code/app than anything wrong with send_blob.

Comment: :i tried this approach to pass the blobinfo through the URL,but the problem was that i can't get this key(info)from the URL in class ServerHandler?